# Image with lots of reflections is split in half in the final render, but not in the render preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: Left: Render Preview (from camera perspective) Right: Final Render]

I rendered this image of lots of metallic spheres. The render preview looks fine, but the final render is split diagonally, each half showing unrelated things. I've tried moving the camera and lighting around, but the issue persists. Both halves change when anything is altered. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you unhidden everything in the viewport (Alt H)?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was caused by a glass pane which was hidden in the render preview but was present in the final image. The glass distorted the render.